# google map api v2 zoom having center and distance between southwest and northeast

Tags: android, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to perform a zoom on a region in google map

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast), padding)
```

the problem is that i dont have: southwest and northeast points

I just have the center of the map (LatLnt) and the distance in meters between southwest and northeast,

I'd like to know how  to calculate southwest and northeast points from map_center and the distance?

any help is welcome

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you are using a square map. In other words that the angle from the starting point is 45 degrees (also assuming that the map is flat which means the distances are small). I am also assuming that you are not at either of the poles (yeah I know duh!).

Ok with that in mind it is simple geometry. Since you know the start point and the length from the Southwest corner to the Northeast corner I use half this distance as that is the distance from the starting point to each of these points. I am then finding the x and y component (which is the same with a square map) of this "half distance". To do this I just use the formula latlongOffset equals half of the "half distance" times the square root of 2.

the code is as follows (you provide a LatLng startPoint, Double someDistance, and int padding):

```
LatLng southwest, northeast;
Double swLat, neLat, swLng, neLng;
Double halfSomeDistance = someDistance / 2.0;
Double latlongOffset = halfSomeDistance * Math.sqrt(2.0) / 2.0;
swLat = startPoint.latitude - latlongOffset;
swLng = startPoint.longitude - latlongOffset;
neLat = startPoint.latitude + latlongOffset;
neLng = startPoint.longitude + latlongOffset;
southwest = new LatLng(swLat, swLng);
northeast = new LatLng(neLat, neLng);
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast), padding));
```

If you are not using a square map you will need to use right triangle geometry to get the latOffset and lngOffset as they will not be the same.

I hope this helps.